# Changing EasyJet reservation: what happens to my Extra Legroom surcharge?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, bookings, easyjet

On EasyJet, to bring a personal item on board in addition to a cabin bag, I had to select an Up Front or Extra Legroom seat (with a surcharge).

If I change my reservation to another flight, will I have to pay the surcharge again to select an Up Front or Extra Legroom seat on the new flight? If so, will the surcharge from the original flight be refunded?

Comment: The way I understand EasyJet's rules, after reading their Fees and Charges page, you'll pay a "Flight Change Fee" which has the note: _*For flight changes, in addition to the 'Flight change fee' stated above, you will also need to pay the difference in price between the cost of the original flight booked and the cost of the flight at the time the change is made. No refund will be made if the cost of the flight is lower at the time of the change._ So if your new flight includes the Up Front fee, and is the same or more, you pay the difference, if less, they do not refund the difference.

Comment: I booked flights to Majorca for June 2021 and booked extra leg room seats, when I changed the return flight by one day (my fault) I paid the extra for the flight but lost my allocated seats which will cost me 2 x £20.99, this doesn't seem fair to me!

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience. Given that your answer directly contradicts the other answer here, could you please add more details to help us understand how you "lost your allocated seats"? Have you received a refund of the fee for the original seats? Have you contacted easyJet customer support to sort this out?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From Easyjet on [Twitter:](https://twitter.com/easyJet/status/740819220074729473)

> 'If you've already selected seats, these will automatically be transferred to your new flight so no worries. (1/2)
>
> If the seats you chose are no longer available, we'll allocate the closest match we can find. Any issue, please DM. Anna [(2/2)'](https://twitter.com/easyJet/status/740819473976938496)

Hope this helps.